# Version check error - Permission on Bitnami/Google Cloud

Tags: scheduled-job, filesystem

According to the log, the version check is not being executed: (after a plain/basic deployment of Bitnami CIVICRM package at Google Cloud).

Output log from: ( Administer -> System Settings -> Scheduled Jobs Log)

```
*Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}
Full message: 
Finished execution of CiviCRM Update Check with result: Failure, 
Error message: File not writable*
```

permissions on /opt/bitnami/apps/civicrm/htdocs:

```
-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon    6604 Feb 21 12:28 authorize.php

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon  111736 Feb 21 12:28 CHANGELOG.txt

-rw-r--r--  1 bitnami bitnami      4 Mar 12 18:55 composer.json

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon    1481 Feb 21 12:28 COPYRIGHT.txt

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon     720 Feb 21 12:28 cron.php

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami bitnami    720 Mar 14 20:19 cron.phpbkp

drwxr-x---  4 bitnami daemon    4096 Mar  8 02:32 includes

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon     529 Feb 21 12:28 index.php

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon    1717 Feb 21 12:28 INSTALL.mysql.txt

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon    1874 Feb 21 12:28 INSTALL.pgsql.txt

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon     703 Feb 21 12:28 install.php

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon    1298 Feb 21 12:28 INSTALL.sqlite.txt

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon   17995 Feb 21 12:28 INSTALL.txt

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon   18092 Nov 16  2016 LICENSE.txt

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon    8710 Feb 21 12:28 MAINTAINERS.txt

drwxr-x---  4 bitnami daemon    4096 Mar  8 02:32 misc

drwxrwxr-x 42 bitnami daemon    4096 Mar  8 02:32 modules

drwxr-x---  5 bitnami daemon    4096 Mar  8 02:32 profiles

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon    5382 Feb 21 12:28 README.txt

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon    2189 Feb 21 12:28 robots.txt

drwxr-x---  2 bitnami daemon    4096 Mar 11 20:39 scripts

drwxr-x---  4 bitnami daemon    4096 Mar  8 02:32 sites

drwxrwxr-x  7 bitnami daemon    4096 Mar  8 02:32 themes

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon   19986 Feb 21 12:28 update.php

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon   10123 Feb 21 12:28 UPGRADE.txt

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon    2200 Feb 21 12:28 web.config

-rw-r-----  1 bitnami daemon     417 Feb 21 12:28 xmlrpc.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `<civiroot>/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php`, it looks like the file downloaded is `version-info-cache.json`.  On my installs, that's in the `upload` folder.  Since that looks like a Drupal install, check the permissions on `<webroot>/sites/defailt/failes/civicrm/upload` and see if the web server user has write permissions.